# Programmatic delivery of emails via SendGrid from PHP (bulk emails)

Tags: php, sendgrid

We have been using SendGrid for some time for transactional email delivery, however - we are starting to send bulk packages of email at various intervals in an automated manner.

We are trying to find a way to send these bulk emails to sendgrid for delivery instead of our current process (looping over a list of users and sending the email iteratively)

*Using something other than sendgrid is not an option*

We need to basically have a way to upload a list of users, replacement values for keywords in the email: %first_name%, %username% etc - in order to send these emails to users.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this within the existing SendGrid infrastructure.

You sound like you'd be a good fit for the [SendGrid Marketing Email API](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/index.html). With this API, you can [add users to lists](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/emails.html#-add) with custom fields (e.g. username); create [email templates](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/newsletters.html#-add) (complete with substitution for custom fields; assign different [lists to email templates](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/recipients.html#-add), and then [schedule them](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/schedule.html#-add) to send.

The other option is to use [SendGrid's SMTPAPI](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html) with [Substitution Tags](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html). Here you can specify any amount of arbitrary fields and then send it to the emails you specify using one API call.

Comment: If the messages are mostly the same for all users, the Marketing Email is a good choice. If the messages are heavily customized, I'd lean more toward the Substitution Tags.

Comment: Is it possible to combine Substitution Tags with the Template Engine?

Comment: Yes, Substitution Tags are meant to be paired with the Template Engine so that you may change values within templates.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but if it was me I would use ParallelCurl. I've used it in the past to send bulk SMS and it worked great for me. The project hasn't been updated in a while though, but it works.

Have a look:

https://github.com/petewarden/ParallelCurl

Good Luck.